# Adding missing values after applying aggregate in R

Tags: r, aggregate, mean, missing-data

I am trying to calculate monthly mean from daily values. My data has too many missing values and I want to fill them with NA values.
For example this is the desired output:

```
"MM","YY","RR"
10,1961,NA
10,1962,NA
10,1963,NA
10,1964,NA
10,1965,NA
10,1966,NA      
10,1967,NA
10,1968,NA
10,1969,NA
10,1970,NA  
10,1971,14.8290322580645
10,1972,5.92903225806452
10,1973,7.10645161290323
10,1974,9.25806451612903
10,1975,6.13225806451613
10,1976,NA
10,1977,NA
10,1978,NA
10,1979,11.358064516129
10,1980,NA
10,1981,20.8354838709677
10,1982,NA
10,1983,NA 
10,1984,7.4741935483871
10,1985,NA
10,1986,NA
10,1987,NA
10,1988,NA
10,1989,NA
10,1990,NA
10,1991,NA
10,1992,NA
10,1993,NA
10,1994,NA
10,1995,NA
10,1996,NA
10,1997,NA
10,1998,NA
10,1999,NA
10,2000,NA
10,2001,12.2548387096774
10,2002,7.19354838709677
10,2003,4.34193548387097
10,2004,8.09354838709677
10,2005,10.3354838709677
10,2006,5.49677419354839
10,2007,9.58709677419355
10,2008,NA
10,2009,NA
10,2010,17.4548387096774
```

The test data can be downloaded from this link:
[Link to Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/spwpoukrli5p715/test.csv?dl=0)

I am using the aggregate function to calculate the mean

Below is my script:

```
library(plyr)
dat<- read.csv("test.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")
dat[dat == -999]<- NA
dat[dat == -888]<- 0

monthly_mean<-aggregate(RR ~ MM + YY,dat,mean)

#Filter August Only
oct<-monthly_mean[which(monthly_mean$MM == 10),]
dat2 <- as.data.frame(oct)

#monthly_mean <- ddply(dat,.(MM, DD), sumaprise, mean_r = 
mean(RR,na.rm=TRUE))

write.table(dat2,file="test_oct.csv",sep=",",col.names=T,row.names=F, na="NA")
```

Problems:

[1] When I ran this script, the missing years are also removed.

I'll appreciate any suggestions on how to do this correctly in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retain the NA columns by changing the aggregate function to,

```
monthly_mean<-aggregate(RR ~ MM + YY,dat,mean,na.action=na.pass)
```

Comment: Also, I think you meant oct in the following line, 
    dat2 <- as.data.frame(oct) # not apr